# Appropriate statistical test for stacked barplot?

Tags: regression, p-value

I was wondering what would be an appropriate statistical test for the following stacked barplot. We are trying to compare how isoform expression (first image) and isoform proportion varies with isoform subtype across sample.

[image: first image]

[image: second image]

First image is the normalized counts cpm across samples (x axis) and Abundance (y axis)

At present, I am using the following

```
cpm_chisq = kruskal.test(variable ~ value, data = cpm_df_melt)
```

I was not sure what statistical test to use.

cpm_chisq = kruskal.test(variable ~ value, data = cpm_df_melt)

Comment: Statistical tests relate to statistical hypotheses within statistical models, not to plots of the data. You will need to explain your data a bit more and suggest a hypothesis that you wish to test. Otherwise the answer might be that the plots are your answer to a question of "how isoform expression (first image) and isoform proportion varies with isoform subtype across sample".

Comment: So the question that we are trying to answer is: Is there a statistically significant difference between isoform proportion in these various subtypes across samples.

Comment: And same for isoform abundance.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to be evasive, but you have re-stated the portion of the original question that I quoted. That does not help me understand anything! What does a "sample" consist of? What is the distinction between dark blue and light blue? Do you want to test light blue against dark blue? Should I be looking at the variability between "samples" or imputing it within? Is a null hypothesis that the isoform expression is constant across samples biologically plausible?

Comment: The barplots indicate isoform proportion. There are different types of isoforms. The barplots are colored by isoform types. I am trying to answer if the difference in barplot of each sample is statistically significant. I am confused as to what statistical test to use. I am wondering if a 2 way anova test where I compare the proportions with respect to sample and isoform type be ideal test to use. In that case the interaction variable sample.isoformtype (if its significant) would answer my question. But I am not totally confident if its the right answer. Thus asking it here.

Comment: Sorry, but you are not really doing much to help me understand the system. What are the samples? I need to know how to determine the variability that is relevant to a comparison. How does the bar plot work? If there is no light blue then is the light blue zero, or is it the same as the dark?  Are you interested in just the bars with two colours? Why does one bar have three colours?